# No article vs plurarlize

Tags: articles

> When it comes to bear, Dr. Reab is more knowledgeable than anyone in this university

> When it comes to bears, Dr. Reab is more knowledgeable than anyone in this university

Are these two sentences have exact same meaning and nuance, even no slight difference? Are these two grammatically sound?

Comment: [“come/bring to bear”](https://www.google.com/search?q=come+to+bear+phrase) is an idiomatic phrase. I have never seen *bears* used in this way. But I am not sure your example uses it correctly. What is the source?

Comment: Are you talking about the animals? PLEASE tell us.

Answer (score 1):

> When it comes to bear, Dr. Reab is more knowledgeable than anyone in this university

I may prefer an indefinite article before *bear.* That would make it generalized.

However,

> When it comes to bears, Dr. Reab is more knowledgeable than anyone in this university

looks better to me because when you *generalized* things, you put a zero article. If you put a definite article for that plural word, it would make it *specific bears* of a particular sanctuary or a specific group of bears mentioned earlier in the context.

Comment: So if you have to choose from between "to bears" and "to a bear", which one do you think sounds better?

Comment: Of course *bears.* Because, I want to talk about *bears* in **general.**  Put zero article *to talk about plural and uncountable nouns or when talking about [things in general](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/radio/specials/1113_gramchallenge30/).*